# VScode: Error:ADB not founded in this machine (Flutter and Android SDK)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, adb

I installed AndroidSdk and Vscode, when i connect usb cable i managed to deploy my application on my phone. on terminal the command works:

```
adb devices
```

i installed the adb pplugins for Vscode but when i try to connetc, i have an error about adb not found, even if i launch terminal ins vscode and adb , the command is not found.

console errror:

```
[Extension Host] [LOG] Not founded in common folder Error: Command failed: adb devices
/bin/sh: line 1: adb: command not found

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:880:11)
    at Object.execSync (node:child_process:951:15)
```

and

```
workbench.desktop.main.js:754 Error:ADB not founded in this machine
workbench.desktop.main.js:1629 Extension Host
workbench.desktop.main.js:1629 /bin/sh: line 1: adb: command not found
/bin/sh: line 1: adb: command not found
```

What i am doing wrong ? i already tried a lot of configurations with bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/xxxxxxx/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

in normal terminal command is working...

this is the plugins (the most installed)

[image]

i use Linux centos

Comment: There are multiple adb plugins for vscode, please add a link to the plugin so that we know which one you use.